# Does MonoTouch.Dialog support an (alphabetic) index?

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

With `UITableView` one can add a quick navigation (like in contacts on iOS) on the right side. Does MT.Dialog also support this? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's supported.

Look at the [sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample) bundled with [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) in the GIT repository. Start it and select the **[Index sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/Sample/DemoIndex.cs)** under **Container features**.

Comment: Ah! A bit hidden in the Source, that's why I missed it. Thanks!